# How to change module.exports to import and export?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, import, export

```
module.exports = function (idx) {
   this.camera = idx;
};

module.exports.CONFIG = function () {
  return Promise.resolve([]);
 };
module.exports.CONFIG.FLOOR = function () {
  return Promise.resolve([]);
}
```

I have a file that contains code like above.
I require this file and console.log it. It only shows

```
function (idx) {
   this.camera = idx;
}
```

Why other attributes are hidden?

And if I delete first module.exports paragraph and console.log it, it shows an anonymous function(or default function ?) in CONFIG.

```
{ CONFIG:
  { [Function]
    FLOOR: [FUNCTION]
   }
}
```

I am wondering how to change it to import/export type instead of module.exports/require?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have both *named exports* and a *default export*. When exporting, that would look something like:

```
// Default export:
export default function (idx) {
  this.camera = idx;
};
function CONFIG() {
  return Promise.resolve([]);
}
CONFIG.FLOOR = function () {
  return Promise.resolve([]);
}
// Named export:
export CONFIG;
```

Then, when importing them, you need to both import the default and the named:

```
import idxFn, { CONFIG } from '../foo';
      ^^^^^ default import
               ^^^^^^ named import
```

You'll then be able to access `FLOOR` by referencing `CONFIG.FLOOR`.

But, note that having a function which is a *property of another function* is *really weird*. You might consider exporting `FLOOR` as another named export instead, just like `CONFIG`:

```
// Default export:
export default function (idx) {
  this.camera = idx;
};
// Named exports:
export function CONFIG() {
  return Promise.resolve([]);
}
export function FLOOR () {
  return Promise.resolve([]);
}
```